# Rust Connecting To SQL Server Timing Out Issue

Tags: rust

I'm using docker to run [microsoft-azure-sql-edge](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge) on my MacBook M3

Part of Cargo.toml

```
tokio = { version = "1.35.1", features = ["full"] }
tokio-util = { version = "0.7.10", features = ["compat"] }

tiberius = "0.12.2"
bb8 = "0.8.1"
bb8-tiberius = "0.15.0"
futures-util = "0.3.30"
```

Here is my code to connect to SQL Server:

```
use tiberius::{Config as TiberiusConfig, AuthMethod, Client};
use bb8::Pool;
use bb8_tiberius::ConnectionManager;

pub struct SQLServer<'a> {
    pub host: &'a str,
    pub port: &'a str,
    pub database: &'a str,
    pub user: &'a str,
    pub password: &'a str,
    pub query: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> SQLServer<'a> {

    pub fn new(host: &'a str, port: &'a str, database: &'a str, user: &'a str, password: &'a str, query: &'a str) -> SQLServer<'a> {

        SQLServer {
            host,
            port,
            database,
            user,
            password,
            query,
        }
    }

    pub async fn check(&self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

        let port = self.port.parse::<u16>().unwrap();

        let mut config = TiberiusConfig::new();
        config.host(self.host);
        config.port(port);
        config.database(self.database);
        config.authentication(AuthMethod::sql_server(self.user, self.password));
        config.trust_cert();
        
        let manager = ConnectionManager::new(config); //.using_named_connection();
        let pool = Pool::builder().max_size(20).build(manager).await?;
        
        let mut conn = match pool.get().await {
            Ok(conn) => conn,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("An error occurred: {}", e);
                return Err(Box::new(e));
            }
        };

        let rows = match conn.query(self.query, &[]).await {
            Ok(rows) => rows,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("An error occured: {}", e);
                return Err(Box::new(e));
            }
        };

        println!("Found:\r {:?}", rows);
        
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The problem I have is trying to get a connection from the pool:

```
let mut conn = match pool.get().await {
    Ok(conn) => conn,
    Err(e) => {
        println!("An error occurred: {}", e);
        return Err(Box::new(e));
    }
};
```

The error is always An error occured: Timed out in bb8

The application run

Now, I can use DBeaver and other software with the same connection settings without issues. I noticed on some searches that this is an issue, but I haven't found a workaround. Do you have any suggestions on a fix? It's driving me crazy.

**UPDATE 1**
Only SQL Server is running in Docker.
I modified the code to use the client only without pooling:

```
let mut config = TiberiusConfig::new();
config.host("localhost");
config.port(1433);
config.database("<database>");
config.authentication(AuthMethod::sql_server("<user>", "<password>"));
config.trust_cert();

println!("Address: {:?}", config.get_addr());

let tcp = TcpStream::connect(config.get_addr()).await?;
let tcp = tcp.compat_write();        

let timeout_duration = Duration::from_secs(10); // 10 seconds for example
let connect_future = Client::connect(config, tcp);

let mut client = match timeout(timeout_duration, connect_future).await {
    Ok(Ok(client)) => {
        // Connection successful
        println!("Connection successful");
        client
    }
    Ok(Err(e)) => {
        // Error in connecting
        print!("Error in connecting: {}", e);
        return Err(Box::new(e));
    }
    Err(_) => {
        // Connection attempt timed out
        println!("Connection attempt timed out {}", e);
        return Err("Connection timeout".into());
    }
};

let rows = client.simple_query(self.query).await?.into_first_result().await?;

for row in rows {
    println!("{:?}", row); // Process each row as needed
}

Ok(())
```

The address is

```
Address: "localhost:1433"
```

And the error seems to be trying to connect to the database:

```
Err(_) => {
    // Connection attempt timed out
    println!("Connection attempt timed out {}", e);
    return Err("Connection timeout".into());
}
```

**Update 2**
I moved my code to Windows, and everything is working, so it seems that my Mac M3 is having an issue connecting to SQL Server even when it's running localhost.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

**Update 3**
Running the same exact code also works on Linux, specifically Ubuntu.  So it does seem its an issue with MacOS

Comment: Please edit your title to be more descriptive of your problem. Can you reduce your problem to verify whether the issue lies from bb8 or tiberius itself? Is this code also ran within docker? Can you provide a complete reproducible example?